# flask-sqlalchemy: Query for records in one table with NO related records in another table (or records of a certain value)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a simple app that helps people call voters. I don't want my volunteers to bug any voter more than once. How can I get a list of voters who have not been called yet? I'm using flask with flask-sqlalchemy.

Voter model:

```
    class Voter(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(80))
        phone = db.Column(db.String(20))
        vanid = db.Column(db.String(20))
        address = db.Column(db.String(255))
        city = db.Column(db.String(255))
        zip_code = db.Column(db.String(20))
        lat  = db.Column(db.Float)
        lng = db.Column(db.Float)
        ...
```

Calls Model:

```
    class Call(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        voter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('voter.id'))
        voter = db.relationship('Voter', backref=db.backref('calls', lazy='dynamic'))
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('calls', lazy='dynamic'))
        time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
        status_code = db.Column(db.String(20))
        ...
```

call.status_code will contain values such as completed,busy,wrong_number, etc.

I want to get a list of all voters who are eligible to be called so that I can pick one to serve to the volunteer. (ie. call.status_code != completed etc. OR has no related call records)

If were to do this in raw SQL I would likely do:

```
Select [whatever]
FROM Voter v
LEFT JOIN Call c on c.voter_id = v.id
WHERE c.status_code IS NULL OR c.status_code = 'busy'
```

I can't figure it out in sqlalchemy. Any insights?

Comment: Have you reviewed the SQLAlchemy Object Relational Tutorial, particularly [Connecting](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#connecting), [Creating a Session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#creating-a-session), and [Querying](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying)?  Here is a (basic) example of what you may be looking for, though you have to consider concurrent access issues.  `session.query(Call).filter(Call.status_code != 'completed').order_by(Call.time).first()`(order_by to start with the oldest records)

Comment: Corrected: `session.query(Call).join(Voter).filter(Call.status_code != 'completed').order_by(Call.time).first()`.

Comment: Thanks Seberius - Can you address how the question in my comment below is handled in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use something like :

```
required_voters = db.session.query(Voter).outerjoin(Call).filter((Call.voter_id == None) | (Call.status_code != 'completed'))
```

**EDIT**

Proposed query :

```
vwcc = db.session.query(distinct(Call.voter_id)).filter(Call.status_code == 'completed').subquery()
this will select all unique voters with completed calls
```

now for the main part

required_voters = db.session.query(Voter).outerjoin(Call).outerjoin(vwcc,vwcc.voter_id == Voter.id) ).filter((vwcc.voter_id == None) & ((Call.voter_id == None) | (Call.status_code != 'completed')))

This I believe will select all Voters who :
- don't have a call with completed status
and 
- didn't have a call or their call didn't have completed status
Remember that I write it from mind so the syntax may be somewhat off

Comment: Wait - Don't I need to somehow filter for the newest call for each person prior to your above query with some kind of group by?  Imagine a voter is marked with Call.status_code = 'busy' and on a later call is marked as 'complete'. Which call would the above query examine on the third pass through?

Comment: This query will select all Voters which haven't had call yet or their call was not completed. That fails the scenario You described (it wasn't clear before). My advice is to make a subquery with Call.status_code and select distinct voters (id) and use that subquery to filter instead of using Call.status_code != 'completed' section

Comment: ok, I think I follow, but may need you to spell it out for me.

First I create a query that looks for any calls that ARE completed. Something like  `completes = db.session.query(Call).filter(Call.status_code == 'complete')`

Then I need to somehow query for voters whose id is NOT contained in the list of voter_ids of the completes query?  How do I write that?

Comment: As @Pawel said, what you want to do is a bit more complicated. You have to consider how you want to prioritize voters first, as that will affect how you want to do queries. It also runs into a concurrency issue, consider: Volunteer 1 requests a new voter. A few seconds later, Volunteer 2 requests a voter and gets the same voter because V1 has not completed their call and updated the voter's status code. V1 completes the call while V2 receives a busy signal. V1 marks the call complete, but V2 is slow and overwrites the status code with busy.

Comment: Edited my answer with a proposed query